# Find the maximal possible value of the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $x_{1},...,x_{100}$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $x_{i}+x_{i+1}+x_{i+2} \leq 1$ for all $i=1,....,100$ (we put $x_{101}=x_{1}, x_{102}=x_{2})$ Find the maximal possible value of the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{100} x_{i}x_{i+2}$$

**It's hard problem, any help guys? it's Olympiad question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_{2i}=0, x_{2i-1}=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $i=1,...,50$. Then we have $S=50\cdot \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{2}=\frac{25}{2} $. So, we are left to show that $S\leq \frac{25}{2}$ for all values of $x_{i}$'s  satisfying the problem conditions.

Consider any $1\leq i\leq 50.$ By the problem condition, we get $x_{2i-1}\leq 1-x_{2i}-x_{2i+1}$ and $x_{2i+1}\leq 1-x_{2i}-x_{2i+1}$  Hence by the AM-GM inequality we get $$x_{2i-1}x_{2i+1}+x_{2i}x_{2i+1}\leq (1-x_{2i}-x_{2i+1})x_{2i+1}+x_{2i}(1-x_{2i}-x_{2i+1})= (x_{2i}+x_{2i+1})(1-x_{2i}-x_{2i+1})\leq \left ( \frac{(x_{2i}+x_{2i+1})+(1-x_{2i}-x_{2i+1})}{2} \right )^{2}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Summing up these inequalities for $i=1,...,50$ we get the desired inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^{50}(x_{2i-1}x_{2i+1}+x_{2i}x_{2i+1})\leq 50\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{25}{2}$$
and we are done.